# Log4j Property file dynamic path setup

Tags: logging, jboss, log4j, log4j2

We have a JBoss Server which has 6 instances named as cim_ms1,cim_ms2,...cim_ms6.In the java code we have Log4g.properties and log file path is /home/crm/logs/cim. Right now,for all 6 instances the logfile is being created at home/crm/logs.But it is required that for all 6 instances,the log file is created at home/crm/logs/cim_ms1 for cim_ms1,home/crm/logs/cim_ms2 for cim_ms2 and so on.The logs should also go in their respective log file paths correctly . cim_ms1,cim_ms2 etc. are the server names.How should I get these paths dynamically in log4g properties?

Answer (score 1):

I assume you want to use the same log4j2.xml configuration file for all instances. You can use property substitution to target separate log files. Here is an example configuration:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<Configuration status="warn">
  <Properties>
    <!-- default to use if system property is not specified -->
    <Property name="instance">default_instance</Property>
  </Properties>
  <Appenders>
    <File name="MyFile" fileName="home/crm/logs/${sys:instance}/myapp.log">
      <PatternLayout>
        <Pattern>%d %p %c{1.} [%t] %m%n</Pattern>
      </PatternLayout>
    </File>
  </Appenders>
  <Loggers>
    <Root level="trace">
      <AppenderRef ref="MyFile"/>
    </Root>
  </Loggers>
</Configuration>
```

Now, if you specify system property `-Dinstance=cim_ms1` for the 1st instance, `-Dinstance=cim_ms2` for the 2nd instance etc., each instance will log to a separate log file.

Instead of system properties, the above property can also be specified in a file named `log4j2.component.properties` by including this file in the classpath of the application.

Comment: Sorry I am not familiar enough with JBos... it should be in the JBoss documentation. Or put it in a file called `log4j2.component.properties` in the classpath of your web application.

Comment: Thanks Remko for the answer.Please let me know where exactly this System Property has to be set in host.xml?My Host.xml is of the type:
<server name=cim_ms1>
server details
</server>
<server name=cim_ms2>
server details
</server>
Please suggest.